# Password validation in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I"m trying to validate password field to show an alert when the validation fails

Here's what I've tried so far but it's not working. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
class PasswordForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {value: ''};

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({value: event.target.value});
    }

    validate(event) {
        var pass = event.target.value;
        var reg = '/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,32}$/';
        var test = reg.test(pass);
        if (test) {
            alert('pass');
        } else{
            alert('fail');
        }
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        if(this.state.value.length < 8) {
            return false;
        }

        alert('A password was submitted that was ' + this.state.value.length + '    characters long.');
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <label>
                    Password:&nbsp;
                    <input type="password" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} onInput={this.validate}/>
                </label>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <PasswordForm />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

What I want is when the user clicks on submit an alert box pops up if validation fails.

Comment: there is a good plugin for validation work https://www.npmjs.com/package/validator

Comment: Thanks but I would really like to know how to do it on my own. That's why it's just one field.

Comment: `validate()` method haven't been bound in constructor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure about the `regex` you used, so used a simple one that will accept only `upper case characters`.
You are already using the `onChange` method, so using a separate `method` for `validation` is not required, use this `onChange` method that will first check whether `pass` is valid or not then only set the `state` value:

```
 handleChange(event) {
       var pass = event.target.value;
       var reg = /^[A-Z]*$/;
       var test = reg.test(pass);
       if (test) {
          alert('pass');
          this.setState({value: pass});
       }else{
         alert('fail');
       }        
  }
```

Check this `jsfiddle`: https://jsfiddle.net/6q53prks/

Let me know if you need any help.

Comment: @Hosar whats the error in that ? could you please specify which part is not working ? its working for me as i am expecting

Answer (score 1):

maybe this https://codepen.io/dagman/pen/wgXRyZ

```
class PasswordForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {value: ''};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({
            value: event.target.value
        });
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        const { value } = this.state;
        const re = new RegExp("^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,32}$");
        const isOk = re.test(value);

        console.log(isOk);

        if(!isOk) {
            return alert('weak!');
        }

        alert('A password was submitted that was ' + value.length + ' characters long.');
    }

     render() {
         return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <label>
                    Password:&nbsp;
                    <input type="password" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                </label>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <PasswordForm />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: could you provide any input value that will not result into weak ?? because i used many but not getting success, i tried this also: Abcd#12345*12$QWER

Answer (score 0):

```
 const passwordRegex =
            /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@*()_+\-=[\]{};':"\\|,.<>/?]).{8,}$/;
          var test = passwordRegex.test(e.target.value);
          setPasswordError(
            !test
              ? "password is not Strong"
              : e.target.value.length > 0
              ? ""
              : "password is required"
          );
```